# IPython auto-completion emacs24 doesn't work

Tags: emacs, ipython, emacs24

I'm using emacs24.0.92 with IPython 12.
I took ipython.el file from IPython repository and also tried [this patch](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/204) however auto-completion still does not work for me.
Can someone give any hint about it ?

Answer (score 3):

That's an old question but since I was looking for it:

**1- python-mode.el**

A quick search lead me to this working solution: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc5

**2- jedi**

You still can use the completion given by `jedi.el`:

http://jedi.jedidjah.ch/en/latest/

http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#Jedi

http://aliquote.org/memos/2013/02/11/emacs-auto-completion-for-python

Install with `packages.el` and call `M-x jedi:setup`. Now the completion fires at the third character. We still can not inspect an object with TAB like in a terminal, but with the 1st solution we can.
***edit:*** false, it's just a matter of configuration: http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/released/#configuration (use `jedi:complete-on-dot` to complete as soon as we enter a dot).